# I've just installed Heroku and I'm having trouble with the initial login

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, authentication, osx-snow-leopard

6.8, I've just updated RubyGems and updated git, etc.  I've just started using Heroku and I'm trying to login for the first time and this is the error screen that I get after I typed
 `Heroku login`:

```
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

Error:       No such file or directory - git --version (Errno::ENOENT)
Backtrace:   /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/git.rb:41:in ``'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/git.rb:41:in `git_version'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/git.rb:8:in `check_git_version'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:36:in `start'
             /usr/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku login
Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.22.0 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: can you type `which git` and `git --version`, what do you get?

Comment: and if you have git installed properly, maybe that's a bug (https://github.com/heroku/heroku/pull/1318)

Answer (score 0):

looks like git is not installed.
try to run

```
git --version
```

or just

```
git
```

from your terminal/command prompt and see if it returns something. 
if not, than your environment cant find git.

try to re-install it or try to update your environment PATH var